# how can I loop and perform operations on columns of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I've imported the fitter package which plots the top 5 plots for a distribution of a series

```
f=Fitter(df.distance)
f.fit()
f.summary()
```

distance is one of the columns of my dataframe. how can I apply the fitter function to plot the graphs of each series?

Comment: A column in pandas Dataframe *is* a pandas Series. What do you mean *each series*?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you want to apply `Fitter` to multiple columns in your `df` in a loop:

```
for col in df.columns:
    f=Fitter(df[col])
    f.fit()
    f.summary()
```

Comment: this is resulting in just one graph. I'm trying to reproduce 8 graphs for the 8 different columns in my dataframe, so I'm looking for a loop that'll plot the respective output for column 1, column 2, column 3[seperate ouputs]